# ListView scrolling lag in android

Tags: android, image, listview, scroll, lag

I am having a customized list view in my application, which is showing an image and text.
The Image I am getting from URL, using the code below:

```
private static Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url,
        String saveFilename) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) fetch(url);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public static Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,
IOException {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
}
```

all is working perfect, except the list view scrolling, its very slow. If I disable the images, the scroll speed smooth-ens , but with the image enabled, it lags alot.

Is there any possible way I can reduce or remove this lagging?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do your fetching in the background. 
One of the examples you can use :
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Answer (score 2):

use this library for downloading images in background and caching..
it won't hurt the UI
https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

Answer (score 1):

Are you lazy loading your images?  [See this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview).